# JavaFX Combobox with multiple elements per row?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

Ordinary combobox has one element per row. Is  it possible to create a combobox with 5rows x 5columns? For example, in one row there should be 5 elements in cells 10x10 px.

Now my code is:

```
private ObservableList<Colors> colorList=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private ComboBox<Colors> colorComboBox;

@FXML
    private void initialize() {

     colorList.add(new Colors(1,"#68ba90"));
     colorList.add(new Colors(2,"#b892ff"));
     colorList.add(new Colors(3,"#ff1ecd"));
     colorList.add(new Colors(4,"#c7003d"));
     colorList.add(new Colors(5,"#25c700"));


     colorComboBox.setItems(colorList);

     colorComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Colors>, ListCell<Colors>>() {
                 @Override 
                 public ListCell<Colors> call(ListView<Colors> p) {
                     return new ListCell<Colors>() {

                        @Override 
                        protected void updateItem(Colors item, boolean empty) {
                             super.updateItem(item, empty);
                             Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10);
                             if (item == null || empty) {
                                 setGraphic(null);
                             } else {
                                 rect.setFill(Color.web(item.getCode()));
                                 setGraphic(rect);
                             }
                        }
                   };}
             });
     }
```

But as a result I have 5 rows with one color per row. I don't know how to display several colors per row.

Comment: Did you try a custom CellRenderer?

Comment: I am new to JavaFX and I could not find on my own how to achieve needed combobox look.